# Where can read about available commands i can use as a script in my gitlab CI yml file?

Tags: scripting, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Basically, i'm getting started with gitlab's continuous integration, but having a hard time looking for a guide or documentation that would help me write scripts for the file.

Where can i read about operators, conditionals and instructions i can use for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all read the [Quick start](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/quick_start/)

Here is everything about yml file: [Configuration of your jobs with .gitlab-ci.yml](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/)

I can recommend to use CI lint which can validate your yml syntax. It can save your time ;-)

[image: Pipelines]
[image: CI lint validator]

Comment: Thanks a lot jakub, thats really helpful